# How to create correct multiple filter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to show items of game and I want to filter my output results.
I have panel with multiple filters

[image]

And I don't know how to do it correct. Some filters are similar, maybe it should move to function.

I tried to do like this (for search by name and one filter), but I am not sure is it the best way or no?

```
filteredItems() {
  if (this.activeFilter && this.activeFilter != "all") {
    return this.items[this.activeFilter]
      .filter(
        item =>
          item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      )
      .filter(item => {
        if (this.minLvl !== "" && this.maxLvl !== "") {
          if (
            item.itemLevel >= this.minLvl &&
            item.itemLevel <= this.maxLvl
          )
            return true;
        } else if (this.minLvl == "" && this.maxLvl !== "") {
          if (item.itemLevel <= this.maxLvl) return true;
        } else if (this.minLvl !== "" && this.maxLvl == "") {
          if (item.itemLevel >= this.minLvl) return true;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Chaining filter is fine. However, you can write a single filter and in that delegate to function to match item: `items.filter(matchSearchCriteria)`. Your conditions are not easily understandable, simplify it.

Comment: @fiveelements about conditions. It should work like this: if no set min/max lvl I show items depends on level and plus items which don't have level property

Comment: @fiveelements and about function with criteria, is it possible to use in computed section?